# Format number to always show how many 0's

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I would like to format my numbers to display and replace how many 0's after three 0's

Examples:

```
number     display
------     -------
0.000001   0.0₅1
0.0000003  0.0₆3
0.001      0.001
```

Comment: Why not use scientific notation instead? It's standardized and reasonably widely understood, whereas I think people will find this custom notation confusing. Plus it's already implemented in JavaScript as `Number#toExponential`: `(0.0000001).toExponential()` gives "1e-7".

Comment: It's crypto related , not many understand exponential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example how you can achieve this. I have commented the code. Feel free to modify the example yourself if you wish.

```js
const convert = num => {
  const subs = [ '₀', '₁', '₂', '₃', '₄', '₅', '₆', '₇', '₈', '₉' ]
  const [left, right] = num.toFixed(10).split('.') // break a number by the dot
  const result = right.match('^([0]{3,})') // for 000 and more zeroes
  if (result){
    const length = result[0].length; // get subs size
    return(left + '.0' + subs[length] + right.slice(length)) // join all parts
      .replace(/0+$/, '') // remove zeroes from the end
  } 
  return num // original
}

console.log([0.000001, 0.0000003, 0.001].map(convert))
```